# python rename multiple columns and roundup dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd 
sample = pd.DataFrame({'k1':[1.1455,2.444,3.5,4.9],
                      'k2':['b','c','d','e']})
```

### it can rename columns successfully

```
sample.rename(columns = {
      'k1' : '3',
      'k2' : '5'},inplace = True)
```

### case 1: don't know the problem in the function -rename columns

```
def rename1(df):
    print(df)
    test1 = df.rename(columns = {
              'k1' : 'num',
              'k2' : 'name'},inplace = True)  

    print(test1)

    return test1
rename1(sample)
```

### Q1: Why the output will be none?

### case 2: 1. roundup the number 2. rename all columns

```
def rename2(df):
    print(df)

    test2 = []
    test2 = df.rename(columns = {
      'k1' : df['num'].apply(lambda num : int(round(num))),
      'k2' : df['name']},inplace = True)   
    print(test2)
    return test2
rename2(sample)
```

### roundup data

```
print(sample['k1'].apply(lambda num : int(round(num))))
```

### Q2: How to roundup the value based on the specific column properly?

### expected the result

```
     num  name
0       1  b
1       2  c
2       4  d
3       5  e
```

This is my sample data. I'm new in python. I'm trying to rename multiple columns for my data frame but I don't know the problem.

Comment: what is your question

Comment: oh, sorry. I have updated the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need separate both operations - first `rename` and then `round` column by [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html) with cast to `integer`s by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
sample.rename(columns = {
      'k1' : 'num',
      'k2' : 'name'},inplace = True)

sample['num'] = sample['num'].round().astype(int)

print (sample)
   num name
0    1    b
1    2    c
2    4    d
3    5    e
```

> Why the output will be none?

Because `inplace=True` working inplace, it means no assign necessary.

```
df.rename(columns = {
          'k1' : 'num',
          'k2' : 'name'},inplace = True)
```

But if want assign remove `inplace=True`:

```
test1 = df.rename(columns = {
          'k1' : 'num',
          'k2' : 'name'})
```

Also if  exist vectorized alternative, apply solutions is better avoid. [General order of precedence for performance of various operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316)